# Can't debug using VS2005 on Win7/64 box

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2005

I've got an 32-bit C++ app, "MyOldApp" built with VS2005. I recently changed my dev PC from a WinXP box to a Win7/64 one. On it I installed VS2005,VS2008,VS2010 and VS2012 (in that order).

Then I found I could not launch "MyOldApp" inside VS2005 in the Debug configuation (Release works fine). Error: Unable to start program. This application has failed to start because the application configuration is correct." Windows event log says: Activation context generation failed for "MyOldApp.exe". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC80.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="8.0.50727.762" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

I check the manifest and it confirms this dependency.

So I check C:\Windows\winsxs and find this directory: x86_microsoft.vc80.debugcrt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.42_none_ef74ff32550b5bf0

Then I check VS2005 Help > About, find it at 8.0.50727.42 and realize I never installed SP1 which I must have been using on the XP box. So I set out to update my machine from .42 to .762 but fail. I have tried installing it from here:

[Visual C++ 2005 Sp1 Runtime (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=200b2fd9-ae1a-4a14-984d-389c36f85647&displaylang=en)

and from here:

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1 Redistributable Package MFC Update](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=26347)

While installing, I get and agree to the license agreement, then see the "preparing to install" dialog. Then the installer just silently exits, and I am left with version .42 and my original problem.

How do I get SP1 to install? Thanks.

Comment: You'd have done yourself a favor by not installing VS2005.  Windows changed a great deal since 2005.  UAC and the file system redirector and the registry redirector may well occupy you for a while more.

Comment: Hans: Agreed. I have only one legacy project still using it and marketing keeps promising me we will kill it "soon" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

[Microsoft® Visual Studio® 2005 Team Suite Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5553)

and it was kind enough to run to completion. Launched VS2005 and it told me to do another update, which I found here:

[Visual Studio 2005 Service Pack 1 Update for Windows Vista](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7524)

which also ran to completion. VS2005 Help about now shows version .762 and my app can be run in Debug Configuration.